# Subgroups regarding group axioms

Tags: abstract-algebra

Practice Question
Prove that a group with two elements of order 2 that commute must have a subgroup of order 4?

I went with the approach that a group with order 2, can generally not exist under group axioms unless there is a subgroup with order 4. Friends and I were almost positive this can be proven by contradiction. Suggestions? Solutions? Different approaches?

Comment: The group cannot have order 2, because in addition to the two elements that commute it must also have an identity element. That's at least three elements. Be careful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: There’s only one reasonable thing to try first: let $x$ and $y$ be the two elements of order $2$, and consider $\{1_G,x,y,xy\}$, where $1_G$ is the identity element of the original group $G$.

Comment: We should note that this will be a *direct* proof, not a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @TBrendle: Actually, I was going to let the OP figure that out from the hint.

Comment: That's where I was headed, I simply figured my strategy can be, in a sense a contradiction. I attempted to word my proof by contradiction specifically, to generally satisfy meticulous critics and become a better mathematician. Thank you for your help. More questions are on the way.

Comment: @PythagorasWannaBe: In this case it really is easier just to construct the group of order $4$; recasting the argument as a proof by contradiction just muddies the water a bit. // You’re welcome.